# Redis connection timeout running on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-ec2, redis, redis-server

I have a redis server running on AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux 2, t3.small). The security group is configured for all hosts (development purpose) on port 6379 and also in redis conf, I have set `bind 0.0.0.0` and protected mode off.
Intilally i was able to connect to this redis instance from a python program but when i checked after some time it says

`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:6379. Connection timed out`

I tried creating a new instance but same problem occurs, event tried `bind 0.0.0.0 ::1` but no success.

Python script, I am using to connect:

```py
import redis

h="ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
r = redis.Redis(host=h)
r.mset({"Croatia": "Zagreb", "Bahamas": "Nassau"})
r.get("Bahamas")
```

Comment: This endponint "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com" is your machine's public endpoint? 
If yes, can you confirm if the instance's subnet's nACLs allow inbound traffic on port 6379 and your RouteTable has an IGW for 0.0.0.0?